# iOS Navigator Collapse Navigation Bar, Cover Status Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

When the navigation bar is visible, it also draws behind the status bar. Is it possible to hide the navigation bar, but keep drawing behind the status bar?

My navigation controller is housing a table view, and adding a subview with the frame of the status bar did not seem to work!

For example, what happens in the YouTube app.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a screen capture and codes which can help us to solve your problem.

Comment: Did you want this effect? https://www.natashatherobot.com/navigation-bar-interactions-ios8/